# Can Apache delete a cookie when it gets a certain value?

Tags: apache, cookies, httpd.conf

I would like to set a directive within the httpd.conf configuration file of an Apache web server that if it finds a specific cookie identified by its name (e.g. XSESSION) when this cookie gets a specific value (e.g. XSESSION=LOGGEDOFF) and only for that value, it must be deleted or invalidated, while it must be left unchanged for any other value.

I tried both the following directives (httpd.conf) without success:

`SetEnvIf Cookie XSESSION=LOGGEDOFF Header unset Cookie` 
`SetEnvIf Cookie XSESSION=LOGGEDOFF SetCookie XSESSION=`

Comment: hi, pls try using the "mod_headers" module.

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Cookie "XSESSION=LOGGEDOFF" DELETE_XSESSION_COOKIE
    Header always set Set-Cookie "XSESSION=deleted; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" env=DELETE_XSESSION_COOKIE
</IfModule>

Reload or restart the Apache. Thank you.

Comment: Tried but it doesn't work (the cookie's expiration date is never changed)